# is it possibe to consume external asmx ,wcf ,soap services from .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a requirement to consume all external services like asmx, wcf ,soap based services in .net core to make it as restful and then consume in the response in angular.

I don't see any examples to configure in middleware pipeline in .net core. else we need to use httpclient or web-client in c# classes to consume that. is it better way or .net core recommended way

share your thoughts.helpful if have any examples.

Comment: https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. Essentially, you are making a .Net Core wrapper for the Soap service. There are many samples on StackOverflow for this as well.

You can:
1.consume a .wsdl file
2.point to a svc or asmx
3.use Postman by pointing to the endpoint and then generate the code.

The first two approaches will automatically generate a Reference class for you.

With the 2nd approach, a SoapClientInterface and SoapClient will be generated. You can use the interface for dependency injection.

If you just want to instantiate the Soap client, you can then call methods in your Soap client. The calls will be async.

If you are using DataSets or DataTables as return from the Soap client, they will instead be returned as ArrayOfXElement.

Comment: thank you for your valuable comments. its already done.question has been created 8 months ago.